# Generate swagger.json from code with Swashbuckle V5

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, swashbuckle, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I was using Swashbuckle AspNetCore v4.x.x and I upgrade to the v5.1.x.x. But the code I used in not working anymore, because of the lack of the class "SwaggerContractResolver".

The goal I attempt to is to generate the swagger.json in code of my RESTfull API :

```cs
public static string GenerateSwagger(this IWebHost webhost, string docName, string basePath)
{
    var sw = (ISwaggerProvider)webhost.Services.GetService(typeof(ISwaggerProvider));
    var doc = sw.GetSwagger(docName, null, basePath);

    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
        doc,
        Formatting.Indented,
        new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
            ContractResolver = new SwaggerContractResolver(new JsonSerializerSettings())
        }
    );

    return json;
}
```

```cs
string json = GenerateSwagger(webhost, docName, url);
string path = Path.Combine(path, docName);
File.WriteAllText(path + ".json", json);
```

How can I do to do this working like the v4 but with the new version of Swashbuckle AspnetCore ?

Answer (score 7):

With Swashbuckle V5, you can use .NET Core CLI to generate the swagger contract :

https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#swashbuckleaspnetcorecli

But this work only with .NET Core API. For .NET Framework, you can use this method :

```cs
public static string GenerateSwagger(this IWebHost webhost, string docName, string basePath)
{
    var sw = webhost.Services.GetRequiredService<ISwaggerProvider>();
    var doc = sw.GetSwagger(docName, null, basePath);

    using (var streamWriter = new StringWriter())
    {
        var writer = new OpenApiJsonWriter(streamWriter);
        doc.SerializeAsV3(writer);
        return streamWriter.ToString();
    }
}
```

You can witch `OpenApiJsonWriter` to `OpenApiYamlWriter` if you want YAML swagger contract.

You can switch `SerializeAsV3` to `SerializeAsV2` if you want V2 swagger contract.

Comment: The .NET Framework sample doesn't compile :( ...

Comment: @flowest, what is the error?

Answer (score 0):

For Swashbuckle V5 and newer, you can use the following extension method.
*(If you are using Swashbuckle V4 or earlier, [refer to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77170943))*

```cs
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Extensions;
using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger;

public static class SwaggerExtensions
{
    public static void SaveSwaggerJson(this IServiceProvider provider)
    {
        ISwaggerProvider sw = provider.GetRequiredService<ISwaggerProvider>();
        OpenApiDocument doc = sw.GetSwagger("v1", null, "/");
        string swaggerFile = doc.SerializeAsJson(Microsoft.OpenApi.OpenApiSpecVersion.OpenApi3_0);
        File.WriteAllText("swaggerfile.json", swaggerFile);
    }
}
```

a couple of notes

- you can use `SerializeAsYaml` instead of `SerializeAsJson` if you want .yml file
- you can specify the version of OpenAPI protocol by using [`Microsoft.OpenApi.OpenApiSpecVersion`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.openapi.openapispecversion?view=openapi-dotnet) enum

If you are using the new ASP.NET Core template, you can call this method like this

```cs
WebApplicationBuilder builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
...
WebApplication app = builder.Build();
...
app.Services.SaveSwaggerJson();
...
app.Run();
```