# .net 6.0 : How to generate Swagger.json file on build in .net 6.0?

Tags: c#, .net-core, swagger, .net-6.0, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I want to generate Swagger.Json file on build and use it in API gateway to configure the endpoints.

I have tried following steps but its not working.

Create a tool manifest:

```
dotnet new tool-manifest
```

Install the Swashbuckle CLI tool and add it to the local manifest file: ***But this step fails***

```
dotnet tool install --version 6.4.0 Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli
```

Error :

```
 NU1202: Package Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli 6.4.0 is not compatible with net6.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0). Package Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli 6.4.0 supports:
  - net5.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v5.0) / any
  - net6.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0) / any
  - netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1) / any
  - netcoreapp3.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.0) / any
NU1212: Invalid project-package combination for Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli 6.4.0. DotnetToolReference project style can only contain references of the DotnetTool type 
NU1212: Invalid project-package combination for Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli 6.4.0. DotnetToolReference project style can only contain references of the DotnetTool type 
Package 'Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli 6.4.0' has a package type 'DotnetTool' that is not supported by project 'WebApi'.
```

Comment: there is already a github [issue](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/2288) for this issue with swashbuckle team.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATED: Generate Swagger JSON File: A Method Using CLI without the Necessity to Debug or Run the App for Generation--**

**A. (optional)**  In the API project properties, (1) enable the documentation file, and (2) specify the output XML filename and path.

[image]

Source: Adding Swagger to ASP.NET Core Web API Using XML Documentation

Include the on-build generated file in the Swagger configuration to make all documentation references appear in the Swagger UI.

[image]

**B.** Run the following commands to enable on-build Swagger JSON config file generation and set the path to the Web API project:

`dotnet new tool-manifest`

`dotnet tool install --version 5.3.1 Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli`

the version is optional and should be compatible with the current installed swagger libs

Source: How to Generate a Swagger JSON File on Build in .NET Core

**C.** To test JSON config file generation, run the following command:

`dotnet swagger tofile --output swagger.json "bin\debug\net7.0\APIs.dll" v1`

- the APIs.dll here is the produced dll of the API project
- v1 here is the document name defined in `config.SwaggerDoc("v1"...`

**D.** (optional) You can automate the operation using build events e.g. post build event or by executing commands as background action programmatically.

```
 public class AutoSwaggeFileGeneratorMiddleware
{
    private Process GenerateProcess()
    {
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = "cmd.exe",
            RedirectStandardInput = true,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            RedirectStandardError = true,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            CreateNoWindow = true
        };

        return new Process { StartInfo = startInfo };
    }

    private async Task ConsumeStreamReaderAsync(StreamReader reader, string prefix)
    {
        string line;
        while ((line = await reader.ReadLineAsync()) != null)
        {
            if (prefix.ToLower().Contains("error"))
                _logger.LogError($"{prefix}{line}"); // Log to the ILogger
            else
                _logger.LogInformation($"{prefix}{line}"); // Log to the ILogger
        }
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        using (Process process = GenerateProcess())
        {
            string command = "dotnet swagger tofile --output swagger.json "bin\debug\net7.0\APIs.dll" v1";
            process.Start();

            // Send the AutoRest CLI command to the standard input of the process
            using (StreamWriter sw = process.StandardInput)
            {
                if (sw.BaseStream.CanWrite)
                {
                    await sw.WriteLineAsync(command);
                }
            }

            // Do not wait for the process to exit, and let it run in the background

            // Handle the output and error streams asynchronously
            var outputTask = ConsumeStreamReaderAsync(process.StandardOutput, "Output: ");
            var errorTask = ConsumeStreamReaderAsync(process.StandardError, "Error: ");

            // Continue processing other requests while the batch file is running
            Task.WhenAll(outputTask, errorTask);
        }
    }
}
```

Do NOT forget to use it in Middleware `app.UseMiddleware<AutoRestMiddleware>();`

---

**OLD ANSWER**

Check below practice
The idea works in requesting the swagger.json on execution.

https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/541#issuecomment-358772489

[image]

There is also [another solution](https://medium.com/@woeterman_94/how-to-generate-a-swagger-json-file-on-build-in-net-core-fa74eec3df1) using the build-time, instead.

Answer (score 10):

This solution is **ONLY** for Swashbuckle **V5 or newer**.
 See [my other solution below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77170943) for version V4 and older. 
See [my, yet, another solution below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77258813) if you want to do this while building the project instead of doing that in the code.

---

Add the following extension method

```cs
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Extensions;
using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger;

public static class SwaggerExtensions
{
    public static void SaveSwaggerJson(this IServiceProvider provider)
    {
        ISwaggerProvider sw = provider.GetRequiredService<ISwaggerProvider>();
        OpenApiDocument doc = sw.GetSwagger("v1", null, "/");
        string swaggerFile = doc.SerializeAsJson(Microsoft.OpenApi.OpenApiSpecVersion.OpenApi3_0);
        File.WriteAllText("swaggerfile.json", swaggerFile);
    }
}
```

a couple of notes

- You can use [`SerializeAsYaml`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.openapi.extensions.openapiserializableextensions.serializeasyaml) instead of [`SerializeAsJson`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.openapi.extensions.openapiserializableextensions.serializeasjson) if you want .yml file
- You can specify the version of OpenAPI protocol by using [`Microsoft.OpenApi.OpenApiSpecVersion`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.openapi.openapispecversion?view=openapi-dotnet) enum

If you are using the new ASP.NET Core template, you can call this method like this

```cs
WebApplicationBuilder builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
...
WebApplication app = builder.Build();
...
app.Services.SaveSwaggerJson();
...
app.Run();
```

Comment: Not understanding why your answer had 0 votes. It worked for me, thanks

Comment: @AbdulG the answer was very new, week before, but I want to ask you a question, does the generated swagger file was complete? because in my case it was not complete, but maybe this is because of something I did wrong, I have a  lot of customized swagger a lot, does that work perfectly for you?

Comment: it generates as expected and is complete, the bigger challenge was getting swagger to use the custom .json file

Comment: this requires the web app to be deployed and run (read runtime) while the author wants the swagger file to be generated during build (read build time). making it work during build would make the overall approach simpler since you wouldn't have to actually pull something from your servers (e.g. firewalls, access, etc)

Comment: @aderesh The answer has links to another 2 different answers, one of them goes to the answer that does exactly what you said (generating the file in the build-time) actually, with my setup, that answer is exactly below this comment, please take a look on it

Comment: @aderesh see the third line of the answer it has the link, if you did not see it, here is the link directly https://stackoverflow.com/a/77258813 which will just scroll your screen a few of CM to the answer, it is most likely that part of that answer is already on display when you are reading this comment

Answer (score 6):

Here is [a good article](https://bartwullems.blogspot.com/2022/09/aspnet-coregenerate-your-swaggerjson-at.html) about generating `swagger.json` file at build-time. 
In summary:

1. In the root folder of your project execute the following command

   ```
   dotnet new tool-manifest
   ```
2. Then execute the following command

   ```
   dotnet tool install SwashBuckle.AspNetCore.Cli
   ```
3. Add the following snippet to your .csproj file of Web Project (the project that contains swagger NuGet packages)

   ```
   <Target Name="CreateSwaggerJson" AfterTargets="Build" Condition="$(Configuration)=='Debug'">
      <Exec Command="dotnet swagger tofile --output ./PATH_WHERE_YOU_WANT/swagger.json $(OutputPath)$(AssemblyName).dll v1" WorkingDirectory="$(ProjectDir)" />
   </Target>
   ```

replace the `PATH_WHERE_YOU_WANT` with the path you want (use already existing folders, this script does not create folders if not exist)

Answer (score 0):

This solution is **ONLY** for Swashbuckle **V4 or earlier**.
 here is the code taken from this [github post](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/541#issuecomment-358772489), cleaned and refactored.

```
using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public static class SwaggerExtensions
{
    private static string GenerateSwagger(this IServiceProvider provider)
    {
        ISwaggerProvider sw = provider.GetRequiredService<ISwaggerProvider>();
        OpenApiDocument doc = sw.GetSwagger("v1", null, "/");
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
            doc,
            Formatting.Indented,
            new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
                ContractResolver = new SwaggerContractResolver(new JsonSerializerSettings())
            });
    }
}
```